# The boundary of a disc has zero measure

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus, lebesgue-measure

Consider that a subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ has measure $0$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$, there is a cover $\{U_{1}, U_{2}, \cdots \}$ of $A$ by closed (or open) rectangles such that
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}v(U_{i}) < \epsilon$$

With this definition, I'd like to prove that de boundary of a disc has zero measure. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Cover the disk with arbitrarily small open sets and you're done.

Comment: But the cover must be enumarable

Comment: A disk would be compact so you only need a finite number of arbitrarily small sets. Those covers will be more numerous when $\epsilon$ is smaller.

Comment: @CyclotomicField it is not clear a priori that the number of rectangles needed does not grow too fast, or is it?

Comment: @CyclotomicField you cannot guarantee that the sum of the volumes of the open sets of the finite cover will be less than $\epsilon$